# Tutorial pubsub is compiling but not running

Tags: ros, java, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am trying to run the pubsub tutorial using gradle.

The program compiles fine but when I try to run the listener program using the command;

$ ./build/install/rosjava_wiki_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_wiki_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker

it gives the following errors;

Loading node class: org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker
Exception in thread "main" org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: Unable to locate node: org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker
at org.ros.RosRun.main(RosRun.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at org.ros.internal.loader.CommandLineLoader.loadClass(CommandLineLoader.java:239)
at org.ros.RosRun.main(RosRun.java:54)

Can you please help me in figuring out what is going on. I did a little digging and my CLASSPATH variable is appearing blank but I am not sure how I can set it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55251/tutorial-pubsub-is-compiling-but-not-running/) by [mfahad](https://answers.ros.org/users/4172/mfahad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2013-02-19**:
I can't reproduce this issue. Make sure you've followed the instructions exactly. For instance, I see that you've renamed the directory. Depending on how you went about this, it could be part of your problem.

**Comment by [mfahad](https://answers.ros.org/users/4172/mfahad/) on 2013-02-19**:
Hi Damon, actually just today I realized it might not be because of rosjava. I was trying to compile and run a different java program and it gave me a similar exception and failed to run. So I think that my CLASSPATH is not right. When I try echo $CLASSPATH, it is blank. Any idea on the right path?

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2013-02-21**:
The class path will be set automatically by the scripts Gradle generates.

**Comment by [mfahad](https://answers.ros.org/users/4172/mfahad/) on 2013-02-21**:
This is strange then because I was not using gradle for the other program I was trying to run but still that was giving the same exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I C that its an year old, but probably its same as : http://answers.ros.org/question/34092/problem-running-rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/

So probably using this :

```
./rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/build/install/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_torial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker
```

should run this.

---

Originally posted by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) with karma: 339 on 2013-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0